# Will the Indian citizens with US H1B and H4 visas get the Dubai on arrival visa?

Tags: visas, dubai, uae, us-visa

I checked the site of UAE government visa:

https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/do-you-need-an-entry-permit-or-a-visa-to-enter-the-uae

In this, the requirements of visa on arrival for Indians is mentioned as:

```
Indian citizens holding a normal passport and either

- a visit visa issued by the USA or
- a green card issued by the USA or
- a residence visa issued by the UK or
- a residence visa issued by the EU

can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 14 days provided that the visas or the green card is valid for at least six months from the date of arrival into the UAE.
```

It says, having a visit visa issued by USA. I have H1B visa and my wife is on H4 visa. Can we get on arrival visa in Dubai on these visas or not?

Comment: I suspect that the answer is *yes,* and that "visit visa" is simply imprecise language for "visa," but I don't know that for certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of the 14 day visa on arrival, the UAE does not distinguish between visa types. Any nonimmigrant visa is accepted. But both the visa and your passport must have at least 6 months validity. However, you cannot use the I-797. The US visa must be already stamped in your passport.

When you arrive in Dubai, go first to the Marhaba counter to apply for the visa on arrival and pay the fee. You should be charged a total of AED 120 and can pay with cash or credit card. Then take the visa paper and payment receipt that Marhaba give you to immigration and you will go right through.